# MySql query gets null tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

SO this is my query:

```
SELECT user_items.userid, users.id, users.username FROM user_items
LEFT JOIN users ON user_items.userid = users.username
UNION ALL
SELECT user_items.userid, users.id, users.username FROM user_items
RIGHT JOIN users ON user_items.userid = users.username
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the tables that say null?

EDIT:

the desired result is that there are no more tables that say NULL

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I think it'd be helpful if you show what your expected results are.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` need result in both tables

Comment: I think it's possible that you're simply joining on the wrong columns - it would surely make more sense to join from user_items.userid to users.userid - because those fields have matching values. You'll never get a match from userid to username - one is a number, and the other is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible that you're simply joining on the wrong columns - it would surely make more sense to join from `user_items.userid` to `users.id` - because those fields have matching values. You'll never get a match from `userid` to `username` - one is a number, and the other is a string.

And I'm not convinced you need two queries - it looks like a single INNER JOIN should get what you need.

```
SELECT 
  user_items.userid, 
  users.id, users.username 
FROM 
  user_items
  INNER JOIN users ON 
    user_items.userid = users.id
```

I think you need to check your work more carefully and also possibly study the different types of JOINs in more detail so you understand exactly what they are intended to do.